# Is there a way to make a real person in a video appear as if they're a ghost using masks?

Tags: animation, node-editor, masking

How do I overlap two frames in blender to make a person in the video appear as if they were a ghost? What I mean is that I want to make a person in the video transparent like glass, as if they really were a ghost, but I don't know how to do it. A demonstration would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a specific question for a particular part of Blender, so you may have to define the question better. If your shot was static from a tripod then you can simply mix/dissolve the frame with the person over a frame without the person. This will result in any differences in frame being see-through. If the camera was moving it gets harder due to tracking

Comment: You can certainly layer two video tracks and make the top one semi transparent.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm new to using masks.